Render Image shows different angles with missing objects
I’ve prepared a project that includes several point clouds, a volumetric box, and an HDRI image as the background. However, when I render the image, it shows a completely different camera angle than my active camera view. Additionally, some point cloud objects are missing in the rendered view. What I see in the render is only one point cloud and the HDRI background in a top view.
I’ve checked many questions and followed all the suggested solutions. My camera is active, I have no keyframe animation, post-processing and the sequencer are turned off, etc.
Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this issue? Below are screenshots of the project and the render view.


When I change the camera position the render view is also changing but it is not aligned to the camera view.
